# Как добавить C# скрипт из Unity3d в Visual Studio с принужденным рефрешем (Reload/ReloadAll)?

Tags: visual-studio, unity3d

Сейчас если открыта студия, а в `Unity3d` создаем файл (`Create -> C# Script`), то студия хочет, чтоб выбрал одно из действий: `Reload/ReloadAll/Ignore/IgnoreAll`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то что-то и где-то подкрутить, чтобы сразу автоматом, без подтверждения, файл подключался к проекту, как `ReloadAll`, например, и не доставал своим окном, в которое надо постоянно тыкать?

Аналогично при удалении файла из Юнити.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент сам разработчик из `VS Tools for Unity` [признался](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-disable-visual-studio-dialog-file-modification-detected.364919/#post-2482822), что это самая востребованная просьба у разработчиков. Но она для них оказалась удивительно не тривиальной и они работают над этим

Однако, на данный момент, существует скрипт, которым можно воспользоваться. Взят он [отсюда](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-disable-visual-studio-dialog-file-modification-detected.364919/#post-2690972) и [с русской комьюнити](http://unity3d.ru/distribution/viewtopic.php?p=249649) благодаря пользователю **DbIMok**

В папке `Editor` надо создать файл `FileModDialogCloser.cs`, в него поместить код ниже

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEditor;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class FileModDialogCloser {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

        const string search = "File Modification Detected";
        static IntPtr hwnd;

        static void Check() { 
                hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, search);
                if ((int)hwnd != 0) {
                        ShowWindow(hwnd, 5);
                        keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0);
                }
        }

        static FileModDialogCloser() {
                EditorApplication.update += Check;
        }
}
```

Удивляемся! 
Работает и при создании C# скрипта и при его удалении.

Как видим в коде есть строка `keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0);`. Это имитация нажатия клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>, а значит на данный момент это реалицация *Reload*. Для *ReloadAll* нужно сделать так:

```
keybd_event(0x09, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(0x0D, 0, 0, 0);
```

Это нажатие <kbd>Tab</kbd> и затем только <kbd>Enter</kbd>

*Небольшой недостаток:* Окно появляется и отрабатывает событие. Окно скрывается. Происходит это все равно быстро и не надо самому ничего нажимать. Но по другому пока эту проблему не решить.

---

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО:**

Можно создавать файлы для Юнити проекта непосредственно из `Visual Studio`. Юнити будет автоматически их подхватывать и никакие окна при этом появляться не будут.

**1 способ (простой)**:

При использовании `Visual Studio Tools for Unity` - этот инструмент (на сколько я понял) уже интегрирует в студию два шаблона для создания C# скрипта. Поэтому нажав на Solution <kbd>ПКМ</kbd> и выбрав `Add -> NewItem`, то можно наблюдать уже два готовых шаблона:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако шаблон может содержать ненужную для вас информацию, например комментарии `// Use this for initialization`, `// Update is called once per frame` и пр., поэтому можно создать для себя любой шаблон:

**2 способ**:

- Создаем файл из любого места.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Добавляем что душе угодно и удаляем лишнее, например так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Нажимаем `File -> ExportTemplate`

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Выбираем `ItemTemlate`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- В списке отмечаем наш шаблон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Еще раз нажимаем `Next`
- Выбираем имя для Шаблона и его описание и нажимаем `Finish`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Шаблон появится в папке `c:\Users\YOUR_PROFILE\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\My Exported Templates\`, а также в `c:\Users\YOUR_PROFILE\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ItemTemplates\`. После перезагрузки студии можно будет наблюдать этот шаблон в списке также, как шаблоны от `VS Tools for Unity`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [ссылка на видео](https://youtu.be/bTxCNS1DNUs) для большего понимания

---

Happy End!